# Sentences' meaning

Tags: sentence-meaning

Could you please tell me a meaning difference between sentences given below?

> 1. She *gets* admitted.
> 2. She *is* admitted.

> 1. It *gets* repaired
> 2. It *is* repaired

Comment: Generally speaking, "Get + past participle" is a less formal alternative to "be + past participle". Both are used to create the passive voice.

Comment: But *he is CoppperKettle* is not passive. So there's something more here. I'm not sure I can say much more though.

Comment: @JimReynolds - yes, sometimes **is** is a part of a copular construction, while **get** is never used in this role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use *is* to merely link the subject with the complement, or to describe the complement, with no further implication.

She = admitted.

*Gets* necessarily implies that someone or something admitted her (or, for example, always or regularly admits her).

She gets admitted (by someone/something).

Comment: Can we say that *get* can be an event/action verb, while *is* must be stative?

Comment: If action is a regularly/always basis then sentence would like "She gets admit". Right or it remains as mention as it is.

Comment: The following are correct. In passive constructions: *She always gets admitted. She gets admitted every time she applies. She is always admitted. She is admitted every time she applies.*